# Where is the RouteOrder property on the Route attribute?

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

According the [asp.net documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#order) there is a property called `RouteOrder` on the `RouteAttribute`. However I can't find that in code. I can find `Order`, but not `RouteOrder`. Should I assume these are the same?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same. I was following the same article and I ran into this problem (`RouteOrder` does not exist in `System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute`).

I did a quick test in my Web API 2 application to verify:

```
[Route("{name}")] // unconstrained parameter
[HttpPost]
public string Test(string data) {
    return data;
}

[Route("preview")] // literal
[HttpPost]
public string Preview(string data) {
    return data;
}
```

When I hit `api/preview` with Fiddler, `Preview()` is hit since literal segments are considered before parameter segments. If I change it to give less importance to the literal action:

```
[Route("preview"), Order = 1] // literal
[HttpPost]
public string Preview(string data) {
    return data;
}
```

And hit `api/preview` again, `Test()` is hit, in line with the documented behavior of `RouteOrder`. I have no idea why it was renamed, but it's the same thing!